# Change Cakephp routing functionality

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

When I use below redirection it gives xxx.yyy.com/posts/add.

```
Router::url(
     array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add'),
     true
);
```

When I change the last parameter to false it gives xxx.com/posts/add.

```
Router::url(
     array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add'),
     false
);
```

The below link forms xxx.com/posts/add url.

```
 echo $this->Html->link('Add Post', array(
     'controller' => 'posts',
     'action' => 'new'
 ));
```

The below redirection forms xxx.yyy.com/posts/add url.

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add'));
```

xxx.yyy.com this is the base url. Server has multiple domains hosted. 
I have completed cakephp project. I dont want to change anything in hosting.
Can I change in cakephp to behave above codes to point out xxx.com/...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CakePHP base configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration) for that.

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', 'http://example.com');
```

It would be even better to use .htaccess url rewriting, if possible:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If i use configure, I have to change in many place. I can give try to .htaccess

Comment: @jayavel If you use Configure correctly, you should only have to change it in one place.